# "Copy" nested array list

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, deep-copy

I have a nested `ArrayList` of the form

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<PointF>> nestedArraylist
```

I want to create a "copy" `nestedArraylistCopy` of `nestedArraylist` in the following sense:

The elements of `nestedArraylistCopy`should be **independent** copies of the elements in `nestedArraylist`, i.e. should be ArrayLists holding the references to the **same** `PointF` objects in the original `nestedArraylist`.

- Can I somehow use `Collections.copy(dest, src)` to do what I want? The documentation is not exactly detailed unfortunately...
- Does the following code do what I want?

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < nestedArraylist.size(); i++) 
      nestedArraylistCopy.add(new ArrayList<PointF>(nestedArraylist.get(i)));
  ```
- Is there a more efficient and or elegant solution?

Comment: Regarding your second question, you can easily test it..

Comment: Yes, I can and have tested the second option and think it works. However, I wanted to ask about `Collections.copy()` and a more elegant solution anyway, so I thought it would make this question more complete and useful.

Comment: in fact, I don't understand the two bold words in your question, `independent` and `same`....

Comment: **independent** = If you modify the elements of nestedArraylist those of nestedArraylistCopy should not change
**same** = If you modify a PointF in one of the ArrayLists in nestedArraylist, then the corresponding PointF in the ArrayLists in nestedArraylistCopy should change.

Comment: @cgogolin so sounds like you want `List<PointF>` different objects, but share same `PointF` ref with source list. then your way in Q2 should be ok. but keep in mind, if you "changed" the PointF in your copied list, the element source list would be changed as well. btw, this could be tested easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: after you `Collections.copy`, your new List object will contain the same elements as `src` (assuming the size is the same) which means, it holds same `ArrayList<PointF>` objects, hence the `PointF` objects are the same too.  If you cannot get the info you want from the api java doc, read the source codes.

Q2: What you did is different from `Collections.copy`, since your copied arrayList has new `Arraylist<PointF>` as elements, but they contain the same elements (`PointF`) as the source list.

Q3: I don't know. because I don't know what do you want to have eventually. All new objects? Only ArrayList should be new objects, or all references?

Comment: Thanks for explaining `Collections.copy()`. I am not an expert, but will have a look into the implementation next time before asking. What you describe under Q2 is exactly I want to achieve. This is what I tried to describe using the words **independent** and **same** in my question.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge your solutions will update only references, as does `Collection.copy()`. You can use the below method, which I prefer:

```
 List<ArrayList<PointF>> newList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<PointF>>(oldList);
```

A change of the old list would not affected to new list.

I tested your second option and it also has the property that changes to the old one will not affect the new List.

Note - These will also update only the references. If you change elements in your new list it will update old list too. I think Your second array will create brand new objects, but I am not 100% sure about that. I am adding my testing code below for you reference.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Lasitha Benaragama on 4/28/14.
 */
public class StckTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> oldList = new ArrayList<String>();
    oldList.add("AAAAA");
    oldList.add("BBBBB");
    oldList.add("CCCCC");
    oldList.add("DDDDDD");
    oldList.add("EEEEEE");

    StckTest test = new StckTest();

    List<String> newListCopy = new ArrayList<String>(oldList);
    List<String> newListClone = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < oldList.size(); i++)
        newListClone.add(oldList.get(i));

    test.printArray(newListCopy);

    test.changeList(oldList);
    test.printArray(oldList);

    test.printArray(newListCopy);
    test.printArray(newListClone);
}

public void changeList(List<String> oldList) {
    oldList.remove(2);
    oldList.add("FFFFF");
}

public void printArray(List<String> oldList){
    for(int i = 0; i < oldList.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(oldList.get(i)+",");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **clone()** method to make a shallow copy of your object.

```
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nestedArraylist=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> x=new ArrayList<String>();
        x.add("Deepak");
        nestedArraylist.add(x);
        System.out.println(nestedArraylist);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nestedArraylistcopy=(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>)nestedArraylist.clone();
        System.out.println(nestedArraylistcopy);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. I want the elements of `nestedArraylistCopy` to be be **independent** copies of those of `nestedArraylist`.